# Removing duplicates from an adoquery

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a adoQuery and would like to fill a listbox with the results, but with no duplicates.

```
      with Fdeptlayout.ADOQuery2 do
  begin
    sql.Clear;
         sql.BeginUpdate;
         sql.Add('SELECT');
         sql.Add(' *');
         sql.Add('FROM');
         sql.Add(' `MList`');
         sql.Add(' ORDER BY `Basic Name`');
         sql.EndUpdate;

         open;
  end;

  while not fdeptlayout.ADOquery2.EOF do
    fdeptlayout.ListBox1.Items.Add(fdeptlayout.ADOQuery2['Basic Name']);
end;
```

Currently this adds 350 items to the listbox, a lot of duplicates. This is too much. How can I alter the query to remove duplicates from the result? :(  Any help would be great!

Comment: You mean `duplicates` and not `doubles`, I'm guessing. In programming, `double` is a specific floating point numeric type.

Comment: If there are lots of entries for the list I'd also to `fdeptlayout.ListBox1.BeginUpdate` before the while and `fdeptlayout.ListBox1.EndUpdate` after the while loop, which suspends redrawing while you're updating the data

Comment: i dont get an beginupdate or EndUpdate as a option for listbox

Comment: -1 Question based on incorrect assumption.

Comment: -1 your -1, assumption on why it was freezing, but i still needed the duplicates out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the query:

```
     sql.Add('SELECT DISTINCT');
     sql.Add('  `Basic Name`');
     sql.Add('FROM');
     sql.Add(' `MList`');
     sql.Add(' ORDER BY `Basic Name`');
```

`DISTINCT` filters out duplicates, and by selecting only the field you need, you save fetching possibly a lot of unneeded data. Also, other fields in the records may differ, causing DISTINCT to work sub-optimal.

As a general rule: Don't use `*` in queries and only select the fields you actually need.

[edit]

And, as agreed in the comments, calling `Fdeptlayout.ADOQuery2.Next` within the while loop certainly prevents your application locking up. ;-)

Comment: umm still freezing up... but the addition of DISTINCT really helps!

Comment: my bad i had for got the adoquery.next  in the while loop..other then that it works great thanks

Comment: Yeah, that one's important too. I overlooked that (and I tend to forget it in my own code as well) ;)

Comment: Yep ;-) I've learned to write such 'continuation' statements as the first one in a loop's code block

Answer (score 6):

You forgot "Next".

```
  while not fdeptlayout.ADOquery2.EOF do begin
    fdeptlayout.ListBox1.Items.Add(fdeptlayout.ADOQuery2['Basic Name']);
    fdeptlayout.ADOquery2.Next;
  end;
```

Without next you get an endless loop.

Comment: About half an hour after Glen found it himself. ;) Good find nonetheless.

Comment: @GolezTrol When I answered I hadn't read all the comments yet. And as said in the other comments, this is one of the most common reasons with this kind of constructions to get an endless loop.

Comment: yes fixes the freezing but not answer to question of removing duplicates.

Comment: @GlenMorse it's provided a solution to your problem. Removing duplicates would have solved nothing and you would still have the infiniloop. Anyhow, I edited the question so that it's focused on the duplicates now.

Comment: @PieterB I had two issues really, this(duplicates) being the first But appreciate you help.